# How to generate .hex file? (Bluetooth)

Tags: hex, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on BLE 112 module. I have made a bluetooth profile and written some BGScript code, now i want to know how can i generate the .hex file of that? I will be very thankful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can bgbuild.exe that is part of the sdk.

See below

[BLED 112 - update BGScript based firmware with SDK v1.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001811/bled-112-update-bgscript-based-firmware-with-sdk-v1-1-1)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a software called IAR Embedded Workbench for 8051.
Good luck, RFPic